# How to get the last element of an array in solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

How do i get the last element? I feel like i should use .length, but then what? PLease help! I'd really appreciate that! Thanks in adnvance

```
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Players {
  address[] public players;

  function add() public {
    players.push(msg.sender);
  }

  function getTheLastUser() public {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the array length for retrieve its last index.
Then you subtract 1 to this value because array starts from 0.
At this point, you must do a query inside array using last index (retrieved previously).

This is an example:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.0;

contract Players {
  address[] public players;

  function add() public {
    players.push(msg.sender);
  }

  function getTheLastUser() external view returns(address) {
    uint lastIndex = players.length-1;
    return players[lastIndex];
  }

  function getLengthArray() external view returns(uint) {
    return players.length;
  }
}
```